# Erro solicita Ajax(Get) AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Estou tendo um problema quando faço uma solicitação GET pro servidor. A minha *factory* sempre retorna um objeto vazio, quando não deveria.

Então o meu *server* `(localhost:8080/av1/listarCarroEstoque)` sempre que solicitado me devolve o seguinte JSON:

```
[
    {
        "id": 0,
        "chassi": "123455",
        "montadora": "ford",
        "modelo": "alto",
        "tipo": "HATCH_MEDIO_ESPORTIVO",
        "cor": "ROSA",
        "motorizacao": 2500,
        "preco": 599
    }
]
```

Meu arquivo `ListarCarroFactory.js`:

```
app.factory('ListarCarroResource', ['$http', function($http) {

    return {
        listar: function() {
            var dados = {};

            $http.get('/av1/ListarCarroEstoque').
            success(function(data) {
                dados = data;
            }).
            error(function(error) {
                dados = error;
            });
            return dados;
        };
    }
}]);
```

Meu arquivo `ListarCarro.js`:

```
app.controller('ListarVeiculo', function($scope, ListarCarroResource) {

    $scope.opcoes = ['carro', 'moto'];

    $scope.veiculoSelecionado = false;

    $scope.listarVeiculos = function() {
        if ($scope.veiculo == $scope.opcoes[0]) {
            console.log( (ListarCarroResource.listar()) );
            $scope.veiculoSelecionado = true;    
        } else {
            $scope.veiculoSelecionado = true;    
        }
    };
});
```

E meu `Main.js`:

```
var app = angular.module('loja', ['ngResource']);
```

Comment: Não entendi qual o erro, ele retorna sempre o mesmo JSON ?? Aqui não seria $http.get('/projeto/av1/ListarCarroEstoque'). ?

Comment: O problema não está muito claro. Seu serviço em `localhost:8080/av1/listarCarroEstoque` está retornando uma coleção (demarcada pelos símbolos `[` e `]`) contendo um item (demarcado por `{` e `}`). Qual seria o resultado esperado?

Comment: Desculpe, eu escrevi errado a url do server é localhost:8080/av1/listarCarroEstoque

Comment: Quando eu chamo o método listar da minha factory ele me retorna um objeto vazio sem nenhum dado dentro, esse é o problema.

Comment: @LeonardoVillela Eu sugeriria adicionar este último comentário à pergunta, então. Outra coisa - no código presente no pastebin não há nenhuma menção à *resource factory* (mencionada no main.js, módulo 'ngResource').

Comment: Já alterei obrigado @OnoSendai.

Comment: Faça um fiddle dito...

Answer (score 2):

Isto acontece porque a chamada `$http.get` é assíncrona. Ou seja, quando ela é chamada, ela não bloqueia o processamento até que uma resposta da API seja recebida. Portanto, mesmo sem a resposta recebida, as próximas linhas do seu código são executadas e a variável `dados` é retornada antes mesmo de a chamada Ajax ser concluída.

É necessário modificar seu código para que ele seja assíncrono. Por exemplo, ao invés de retornar `dados`, retorne a `promise` retornada pela chamada `$http.get`:

```
app.factory('ListarCarroResource', ['$http', function($http) {

    return {
        listar: function() {
            return $http.get('/av1/ListarCarroEstoque');
        };
    }
}]);
```

E no seu controller:

```
app.controller('ListarVeiculo', function($scope, ListarCarroResource) {

    $scope.opcoes = ['carro', 'moto'];

    $scope.veiculoSelecionado = false;

    $scope.listarVeiculos = function() {
        if ($scope.veiculo == $scope.opcoes[0]) {
            ListarCarroResource.listar().success(function (dados) {
                console.log(dados);
            }).error(function () {
                alert("Erro!");
            });
            $scope.veiculoSelecionado = true;    
        } else {
            $scope.veiculoSelecionado = true;    
        }
    };
});
```